# Centos random slow down

Tags: web-server

I have encountered this twice, the first time I thought it was just random stuff, so I put the investigation on hold until I encountered this again today.

Summary:

- Centos 5.7, sendmail 8.13.8
- High CPU usage by crond and sendmail (between 25% to 100% each)
- super slow disk IO (ssh runs fine until there is disk IO ops, like a simple ls -la)
- 'df -h' gave me a disk usage of 900G on my main mount (about 50% of my total space), I did not manage to track down which folder was using all the space, as the disk was running really slowly (it took 30s to return a 17M usage for one folder)

What I tried to do:

- Kill sendmail, crond, and any rogue PHP processes that was consuming more than the normal amount of CPU
- shutdown httpd, sendmail, mysqld (all of those took 1-5min to shutdown)

Results:

- Cannot kill sendmail process, it keeps appearing at the top with a TIME of 600Minutes+ (I only discovered that there was a problem when I woke up)

None of those worked, then suddenly out of the blue while I was just scanning through logs (very slowly...) it went back to the normal speed again.

a du -h revealed that the 900G of usage is gone and back to 19G (which is what it is supposed to be at), and the sendmail process is killable now...

I am not sure where to start with to investigate this wierd problem, so if anyone can share some tips or shed some light on possible causes thast would be fab!

**EDIT (2011-11-01):**

The only record I found of the process I killed was this one line

```
Oct 31 11:43:08 localhost sendmail[23302]: p9UIT2SB023302: from=[removed, it was not an email address though], size=1152544132509, class=0, nrcpts=1, relay=[removed]@localhost
```

As for cronjobs, I have 2 currently running, both are php scripts which I run once a minute and once an hour respectively.

**Edit 2 (2011-11-01):**

Wait a sec... size is 1152544132509 (about 1TB)... I guess that's what took the space... Now I gotta find what sent that mail. Any suggestions to how I can find the culprit?

**Edit 3 (2011-11-03):**

I found that I had over 10k unauthorized SSH login attempts... maybe the server was hijacked for a hacking attempt elsewhere... I will be switching off SSH login with password and making sure that the authorized keys are really the allowed ones...

I also installed denyhosts to auto block any further bruteforce attacks.

Comment: What jobs did you run in cron? Does sendmail cause high disk IO or anything else? Did you take a look at the sendmail's log?

Comment: wat kind of server r u using? dedicated? vps?

Comment: Dedicated server